# Extend base instance with derived class at runtime

Tags: typescript

I have the following class hierarchy:

```
class Base {
    public BaseMethod() {
        // doesSomeStuff
    }
}

class Derived extends Base {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
    public DerivedMethod() {
        // do some stuff
        BaseMethod();
    }
}
```

My problem now is that at runtime I get an instance of class `Base` and I need to extend that instance to type `Derived`. I do not control the construction of `Base` nor am I the owner of class `Base`.

How is it possible to extend that instance at runtime, so that it becomes an instance of type `Derived`?

```
function someFunction(base: Base) {
    let derived: Derived = extend(base);
    derived.BaseMethod();
    derived.DerivedMethod();
}
function extend(base: Base): Derived {
    // implementation?
}
```

PS: I need to target ES5!

Comment: Is it strictly necessary to change the `Base` object into a `Derived` object in-place? Could you not write a static factory method which constructs a new `Derived` object given a `Base` object to copy its state from?

Comment: @kaya3 no that's not possible for me. Otherwise other objects would lose their references to the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a satisfying solution based on @kaya3's answer. If you do not need to support legacy browsers check out his/her answer!

There is a polyfill available for `Object.setPrototypeOf` that kind of works in legacy IE browsers (at least down to IE9). I found it in the [es6-sham](https://github.com/paulmillr/es6-shim/blob/master/es6-sham.js#L58). It has one caveat that references of the object need to be reassigned.

Here's my solution:

```
class Base {
    public BaseMethod() {
        console.log('base called');
    }
}

class Derived extends Base {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
    public DerivedMethod() {
        this.BaseMethod();
        console.log('derived called');
    }
}

function extend(base: Base): Derived {
    return <Derived>(Object.setPrototypeOf(base, Derived.prototype));
}
function assert(base: Base): asserts base is Derived { }

let b: Base = new Base();

b = extend(b);
assert(b);

b.BaseMethod(); // base called
b.DerivedMethod(); // base called derived called
```

I dislike a bit, the empty assert function. I tried to combine it with the extend function, but I found no way of combining the return types `asserts base is Derived` and `Derived`.

In case someone is interested, I made the `asserts` function generic so that I can use it for more types:

```
function assertExtends<T, U extends T>(t: T): asserts t is U { }
b = assertExtends<Base, Derived>(b);
```

Comment: Nice one. If you write `let d = extend(b);` then the `assert` function is unnecessary, since `d` will have the type `Derived` based on the return type of `extend`. I'm not sure why `b = extend(b);` doesn't do control-flow narrowing without the `assert` function; it ought to.

Comment: @kaya3 I thought about using `let d = extend(b)` and then use `d` instead of `b`, but I didn't want to introduce a new variable. About the control-flow narrowing, I think it should only happen if the code explicitly demands it. In a typesafe language as typescript partially is, implicit control-flow narrowing would be dangerous.

Comment: There shouldn't be anything unsafe about the assignment `b = extend(b);` narrowing `b`'s type to `extend`'s return type, if that's a subtype of `b`'s declared type. If you write `let b: string | undefined = undefined;` then an assignment `b = 'foo';` does narrow `b`'s type to `string`, for example. `b = getString();` does the same narrowing if `getString`'s return type is `string`. I'm not sure why the `Base`/`Derived` example isn't equivalent to that.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible in ES6 using [`Object.setPrototypeOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf). If you give the `extend` function an `asserts` return type, you can even use control-flow narrowing rather than returning the input with a stricter type:

```js
function extend(base: Base): asserts base is Derived {
    Object.setPrototypeOf(base, Derived.prototype);
}

let b: Base = new Base();

extend(b);

b.DerivedMethod(); // OK, due to control-flow narrowing
```

**Warning:** this allows you to create objects with invalid states, if you're not careful. If the `Derived` class has its own property `foo`, then calling `setPrototypeOf` gives you a `Derived` object without that property. It's your responsibility to make sure `extend` adds any new properties the `Derived` object will need.

[Playground Link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=20&ssc=25&pln=12&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAEBCkFNoG8BQ0PQA4FcBGIAlsHIgLIIAuAFgPYAmAFAJQoC+qHqokMAIggBOhAG4J60BAA9KCAHb0Y8CEjSZowWnIiVBOYJVqCWKdOswQcWISwDcZjB3W4CxaAOFj6FGgxPIOLgAzHDkDQi1JGXkmPEQALlIVZkTeIUoYOJVoQn4hUXFTdQB5PAArBAMAOhVKAAVBWkNKAE9rYqDGLIQAGnd8ryqsRua2hGZ7LhAqaDxE5SQAXmg5BAB3JIQ7VFRpWQUuiZ28Ko8C7yo6JgnoAHpb6FoAax2gA)

---

If you are targeting earlier than ES6, there is a [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf#Polyfill), but this only works in Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox; it works by changing the `__proto__` property, but this property was non-standard before ES6, so other browsers did not support it. There doesn't seem to be any other way of getting or setting an object's prototype in other browsers in order to expand the polyfill, so if you need to do this in ES5 on other browsers, you're probably out of luck.

Another solution might be possible by monkey-patching, but `obj instanceof Derived` will be false, meaning it won't really be an instance of `Derived`.

Comment: @daniatic I see. I've edited to mention a polyfill, but this only works on two specific browsers since it relies on a non-standard feature of those browsers. Otherwise it seems quite unlikely there is a solution, but perhaps actually changing the object's class at runtime isn't required to solve your actual problem. In that case, you should ask a new question with the details of what specific behaviour you want to change on the object.

Comment: Thx for your edit. The polyfill still won't help. I need to support IE9+ :(

Comment: Would extending the actual class `Base` solve your problem? You can assign new properties like `Base.constructor.DerivedMethod = ...` in every browser. This would extend every `Base` object, including objects which already exist, without having to call `extend` on each object individually. It would be unsuitable if you only wanted to extend some instances, of course.

Comment: Nice idea, but still not feasible. I need several differently derived types...

Comment: I'm thinking about implementing the Derived class instead of extending it. In the constructor of the Derived class then I pass the base instance and set it as a property. Now I can implement all Base members throught the instance property. This would be a lot of boilerplate and I would need to change all references directed at the base instance onto the new derived object.

Comment: Something like [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?target=1&ssl=19&ssc=1&pln=20&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAEBCkFNoG8BQBIADgVwEYgEtg5EBZBAFwAsB7AEwAoBKFDdAenejpugguwAzQRgC+qcalCQYAEQQAnAgDcEdaAQC2mEAk0IAdhRjwISNOlyIAXCTMBuDMBoH+C7MAo0FDK2dumCCwW6NQEEAB0fkgAvNDRjujiWHiExIHk1PTMrOihVOFRiBEZlLSMTInJOPhE0PJKqnSZ5TkhnNy8-EIiSRKoymAK8YjQcQYIAO52CMyOg8N0iipqY9AT0w0rjNGVqEA) but I still need to think about the caveats that would have.